# Natural Language Processing - Returning results as JSON objects

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, nlp

I am working on completing a Python programing challenge to do with Natural Language Processing and scraping information from BBC News articles. My previous submission of code (shown below) was marked and failed due to not passing the test criteria (shown below). However I am unable to think of any way to make my code pass the test.

From what I can tell the code is failing for a few reasons:

- Escape characters not matching the test code
- Use of "      " instead of '   ' in some variables

This is my code:

```
# Import modules used to complete challenge
import json
import requests
import spacy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Load the Spacy English model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
# Url's stored in a list to test that the scraper function is iterable
url = ["https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-52255054"]


# Function used to scrape a given BBC news article and return URL, Title, Date and Content as a json object
def bbc_scraper(url):
    # Error catching on invalid URL's and connectivity issues
    try:
        r = requests.session()
        page = r.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Double check the URL and try again.")
        raise SystemExit(e)
    # Use beautifulSoup to parse the html content and store it as soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    # Using beautifulSoup to find specific HTML tags within HTML classes
    title = soup.find("h1", class_="story-body__h1").text
    date = soup.find("div", class_="date date--v2").text
    main_content = soup.findAll("div", class_="story-body__inner")
    # Finding all "p" HTML tags within the main content
    news_content_paragraphs = main_content[0].find_all("p")
    list_paragraphs = []
    # Loop through all paragraphs and joins them to the final_article string
    for paragraphs in news_content_paragraphs:
        list_paragraphs.append(paragraphs.text)
        final_article = ''.join(list_paragraphs)
        # Build the json object with content scraped from the website
    results_json = json.dumps({'URL':url, 'Title':title,'Date_published':date, 'Content':final_article})
    return results_json
```

And then this is the test criteria used to test the JSON that my code returns:

```
def test_bbc_scrape():
    results = {'URL': 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-52255054',
                'Title': 'Coronavirus: \'We need Easter as much as ever,\' says the Queen',
                'Date_published': '11 April 2020',
                'Content': '"Coronavirus will not overcome us," the Queen has said, in an Easter message to the nation. While celebrations would be different for many this year, she said: "We need Easter as much as ever." Referencing the tradition of lighting candles to mark the occasion, she said: "As dark as death can be - particularly for those suffering with grief - light and life are greater." It comes as the number of coronavirus deaths in UK hospitals reached 9,875. Speaking from Windsor Castle, the Queen said many religions had festivals celebrating light overcoming darkness, which often featured the lighting of candles. She said: "They seem to speak to every culture, and appeal to people of all faiths, and of none. "They are lit on birthday cakes and to mark family anniversaries, when we gather happily around a source of light. It unites us." The monarch, who is head of the Church of England, said: "As darkness falls on the Saturday before Easter Day, many Christians would normally light candles together.  "In church, one light would pass to another, spreading slowly and then more rapidly as more candles are lit. It\'s a way of showing how the good news of Christ\'s resurrection has been passed on from the first Easter by every generation until now." As far as we know, this is the first time the Queen has released an Easter message. And coming as it does less than a week since the televised broadcast to the nation, it underlines the gravity of the situation as it is regarded by the monarch. It serves two purposes really; it is underlining the government\'s public safety message, acknowledging Easter will be difficult for us but by keeping apart we keep others safe, and the broader Christian message of hope and reassurance.  We know how important her Christian faith is, and coming on the eve of Easter Sunday, it is clearly a significant time for people of all faiths, but particularly Christian faith. She said the discovery of the risen Christ on the first Easter Day gave his followers new hope and fresh purpose, adding that we could all take heart from this.  Wishing everyone of all faiths and denominations a blessed Easter, she said: "May the living flame of the Easter hope be a steady guide as we face the future." The Queen, 93, recorded the audio message in the White Drawing Room at Windsor Castle, with one sound engineer in the next room.  The Palace described it as "Her Majesty\'s contribution to those who are celebrating Easter privately".  It follows a speech on Sunday, in which the monarch delivered a rallying message to the nation. In it, she said the UK "will succeed" in its fight against the coronavirus pandemic, thanked people for following government rules about staying at home and praised those "coming together to help others". She also thanked key workers, saying "every hour" of work "brings us closer to a return to more normal times".'}
    scraper_result = bbc_scraper('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-52255054')
    assert json.loads(scraper_result) == results
```

My code returns the following:

```
{"URL": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-52255054", "Title": "Coronavirus: 'We need Easter as much as ever,' says the Queen", "Date_published": "11 April 2020", "Content": "\"Coronavirus will not overcome us,\" the Queen has said, in an Easter message to the nation.While celebrations would be different for many this year, she said: \"We need Easter as much as ever.\"Referencing the tradition of lighting candles to mark the occasion, she said: \"As dark as death can be - particularly for those suffering with grief - light and life are greater.\"It comes as the number of coronavirus deaths in UK hospitals reached 9,875.Speaking from Windsor Castle, the Queen said many religions had festivals celebrating light overcoming darkness, which often featured the lighting of candles.She said: \"They seem to speak to every culture, and appeal to people of all faiths, and of none.\"They are lit on birthday cakes and to mark family anniversaries, when we gather happily around a source of light. It unites us.\"The monarch, who is head of the Church of England, said: \"As darkness falls on the Saturday before Easter Day, many Christians would normally light candles together. \"In church, one light would pass to another, spreading slowly and then more rapidly as more candles are lit. It's a way of showing how the good news of Christ's resurrection has been passed on from the first Easter by every generation until now.\"As far as we know, this is the first time the Queen has released an Easter message.And coming as it does less than a week since the televised broadcast to the nation, it underlines the gravity of the situation as it is regarded by the monarch.It serves two purposes really; it is underlining the government's public safety message, acknowledging Easter will be difficult for us but by keeping apart we keep others safe, and the broader Christian message of hope and reassurance. We know how important her Christian faith is, and coming on the eve of Easter Sunday, it is clearly a significant time for people of all faiths, but particularly Christian faith.She said the discovery of the risen Christ on the first Easter Day gave his followers new hope and fresh purpose, adding that we could all take heart from this. Wishing everyone of all faiths and denominations a blessed Easter, she said: \"May the living flame of the Easter hope be a steady guide as we face the future.\"The Queen, 93, recorded the audio message in the White Drawing Room at Windsor Castle, with one sound engineer in the next room. The Palace described it as \"Her Majesty's contribution to those who are celebrating Easter privately\". It follows a speech on Sunday, in which the monarch delivered a rallying message to the nation.In it, she said the UK \"will succeed\" in its fight against the coronavirus pandemic, thanked people for following government rules about staying at home and praised those \"coming together to help others\".She also thanked key workers, saying \"every hour\" of work \"brings us closer to a return to more normal times\"."}
```

Obviously I know that it doesn't match the criteria and thats why it is failing but I'm strugging to get the JSON to be in the correct format to pass the test.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: post what you code is returning

Comment: I've ammeded the original post with what the code is returning.

Comment: i think that you need to remove `\` from some parts of you code and add in another, check why test case is containing them.